# How do I select all documents containing a certain pattern in the fields?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

If I have a set of documents of the type:

```
{
    "contactId": "V1234",
    "accessMap": {
        "130134:24": ["RG1234", "RG456"],
        "12345:45": [".....", "....", ..],
        ...
    },
    "documentType"="CONTACT_ACCESS_MAP"
}
```

How can I write a query to select all `meta().id` of the documents where a certain value, in this case `130134:24` exists in the access map?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

`SELECT n for n in OBJECT_NAMES(accessMap) from` access-services `where n like "130134:24%" and documentType="CONTACT_ACCESS_MAP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your JSON document is actually valid JSON like below:

```
{
  "contactId": "V1234",
  "accessMap": {
    "130134:24": [
      "RG1234",
      "RG456"
    ],
    "12345:45": [
      ".....",
      "....",
      ".."
    ]
  },
  "documentType": "CONTACT_ACCESS_MAP"
}
```

You're on the right track with `OBJECT_NAMES`. Use [`ANY n IN expression SATISFIES condition END` syntax](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html) in the `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
SELECT META(s).id
FROM accessservices s
WHERE ANY n IN OBJECT_NAMES(accessMap) SATISFIES n LIKE "130134:%" END;
```

Comment: That worked, just had to tweak it a little bit:

`SELECT META(s).id FROM default as s WHERE ANY n IN OBJECT_NAMES(accessMap) SATISFIES n LIKE "130134:%" END;`